# My selection sort implementation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

please review my code on selection sort algorithm:

```
selectionSort();

function selectionSort(){
    var numArray = [4,34,2,5,12];
    var MIN = 0;
    var totalNum = numArray.length,
        temp = 0,
        next_position = 0

    for(var i = 0; i < totalNum; i++){
        MIN = numArray[i];

        next_position = i + 1;
        for(var j = next_position; j < totalNum; j++){

           if(numArray[j] < MIN){
              temp = MIN;
              MIN = numArray[j];
              numArray[j] = temp;
           }
        }

        numArray[i] = MIN;      
    }

    console.log(numArray);
}
```

After running, the output is:

```
[ 2, 4, 5, 12, 34 ]
```

Comment: A function like that won't be re-usable. You are declaring the array to be sorted inside the function, instead of accepting a parameter.

Comment: Also, a style tip: you're missing a semicolon after `next_position = 0`

Comment: Also about "doing this efficiently", selection-sort isn't that efficient: in terms of time complexity it is `O(x²)`

Comment: usually Array.prototype.sort is enough for most use-cases (in terms of efficiency), without having to code your own sorting function, which is potentially slower, and prone to errors. If you don't want to use `my_array.sort()` you could find a javascript library to do it, that should be well-code, more efficient, and without bugs (also saving you some time)

Comment: @Zorgatone It's probably just a training exercise.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But I thought I should be saying this anyway. I didn't make a proper answer for that reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I would add if I were doing this as a peer review.

#### Nested For Loops:

Nested for loops are hard to read. As an alternative, split the nested loop into a separate, aptly named function, if possible. Perhaps a function that returns the next item to be swapped with? You would take your nested for loop and move it to a function that would return what is currently `temp` if it is there. Then, if there was a return value, you would swap the values. You could even destructure them instead of storing the previous value in a temporary variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Also, by moving the `for` loop into a different function, you only have to do this `numArray[i] = MIN;` if necessary.

#### Naming:

Your variables are lowercase, lower_case, camelCase, and UPPERCASE. I suggest standardizing on one. For one thing, `MIN` looks like a constant to me (from a PHP background), but it is being changed every time in the `for` loop. Also, what about improving the names: `totalNum` is unclear to me. Without looking beyond the naming is that an accumulator that stores the sum of all the items? `temp` could be `previousItem`.

#### Other Items:

- It's typically recommended to declare variables at the top of the function. `j` is declared numerous times.
- You initialize `MIN` at `0`, but then reset it inside of the `for` loop. Why not just declare `MIN` and not set a value.

#### A completely different approach:

Finally, I wondered about using Javascript's `Array.forEach()`. The following is a completely different perspective, but I thought I would throw it out there for you to consider:

```js
selectionSort();

function selectionSort(){
    var originalArray = [4, 34, 2, 5, 12],
        sortedArray = [],
        lowerSortedIndex;
 
  
  originalArray.forEach(function(item) {
    // Arrow function with implied return:
    lowerSortedIndex = sortedArray.findIndex((nextItem) => nextItem >= item);
    
    if (lowerSortedIndex >= 0) {
      sortedArray.splice(lowerSortedIndex, 0, item);
    } else {
      sortedArray[sortedArray.length] = item;
    }
  });

    console.log(sortedArray);
}
```

The arrow function could be re-written as:
`function(nextItem) { return nextItem >= item; })`

I wrote it here if you want to play with it: http://codepen.io/bassplayer7/pen/oBxmbW

Comment: If you're going to go the route of creating an array min function then javascript [provides one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/javascript-min-max-array-values)

Comment: @JamesSnell one difference, though, is that `findIndex()` in my example is finding the item that is the *next one bigger than* the current one. So it's not the largest or smallest. Perhaps it would be even simpler to go based off of the min/max, although without trying it I'm not sure.

Comment: you're probably right, there could be (repeated values for example could prove tricky - I've not looked in detail.)

Comment: Yes, in my CodePen example, I've thrown negative numbers and duplicates at it and it still spits it out correctly.